# Calculate a number (mod)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Calculate: $3^{1234} $ (mod 17)

We're not suppose to use any "tricks" like the little theorem or anything else alike because we haven't learned that yet just the the definition of modulo.

I tried to do this but it doesn't really help:

$3^{1234}=20^{1234}=2^{1234}10^{1234} $

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just notice that $3^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$ and that $1234 \equiv 2 \pmod{16}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing arithmetic modulo $\;17\;$ all along:

$$3^4=81=-4\;,\;\;3^5=-12=5\;,\;\;3^6=15=-2\;,\;\;3^7=-6\;,\;\;3^8=-18=-1\implies$$

$$\implies 3^{16}=1\;,\;\;\text{and $\;3\;$ is a primitive root modulo}\;17$$

Now:

$$1234=77\cdot 16+2\implies3^{1234}=(3^{16})^{77}\cdot3^2=3^2=9$$

Comment: Wait how did you find this out: $1234=77\cdot 16+2 $?

Also, we haven't covered the primitive root.

Comment: Well, after I corrected the nonsense I did, I just divided $\;1234/16\;$ as we were taught in second grade...Forget about the primitive root: it doesn't matter for you now.

Answer (score 2):

Just start computing:  $$3^2\equiv 9\\3^3\equiv 10 \\3^4\equiv 13 \\3^5 \equiv 5
\\3^6\equiv15\\3^7\equiv 11\\ \dots \\3^{16}\equiv 1$$ So now you can just look for the remainder when $1234$ is divided by $16$, which is $2$

Comment: @DonAntonio fixed

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively work this out in stages, each time bringing a square inside the brackets:

$3^{1234} \equiv 9^{617} \equiv 9.9^{616} \equiv 9.13^{308}
 \equiv 9.(-4)^{308} \equiv 9.(-1)^{154} \equiv 9 \bmod 17.$

Comment: Can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: $a^{2n} = (a^2)^n$ means you can keep taking squares into the power. Squares are easy to work out mod $17$.

Comment: I meant the way that you square only the decimal, is that what its called ?

Comment: There are no decimals here, the dots are shorthand for multiplication.